# I updated the Theme File but can't see the changes

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I edited my "custom-script.js" file (themes/js/custom-script.js?ver=9.2.2) in Theme File Editor.
However I can't see changes on live website. In Chrome Dev, I can see thgat the website is still loading 9.2.2.

I go to another tab to solely load this custom-script.js?ver=9.2.3 and I can see the changes exists.

I tried to clear cache using WP Engine and load the website from incognito window, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Are you using some caching plugin on your site? They often cache CSS files.

Comment: yes.. WP Engine.